# installer display for ubuntu 14.04.2 messed up on 4k screen

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.2 on an Intel NUC with HD6000 graphics, connected to a Samsung screen with a native 3840x2160 resolution. The initial grub menu displays fine, but the graphical part of the install is messed up. How do I force a lower resolution or text only during install? Thanks!

Comment: I wound up using 15.04 instead, which didn't exhibit this problem.